# Common video format for TV (old decoder) playback

Tags: audio, video, tv, codec, file-format

I have a PHILIPS TV/Monitor. I want to watch movies from USB flash drive directly on the TV.

The problem is - PHILIPS do not have any updates for the TV software. I requested an update, but request was rejected.

I can play some movies, but most of the files(movies) not showing at all in the USB library. Same for images (pictures). It shows only `jpeg` below 80% quality / `png` only if is too small.

Which software I need to use for encode the video files (I am using ubuntu). And what format and settings I need to use while encoding the video to increase the chance that TV will detect and play the file.

Comment: I would *expect* the TV/Monitor's documentation/manual to list supported formats.  Check the Philips website for your model and look at all the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to have an assortment of pictures and videos, then write down what does and does not work, take it back to your computer and do a MediaInfo on it (windows program that reads the header data and tells the spec and codec).

Generally the older simple media chip usb things in older Tvs would handle Mpeg and Mpeg2 , very similar to dvd, many of them would also take a Xvid or Divx (which doesnt say a lot) the old H.263  not 264 or 265 BPOVs , but not global motion compensation, or many of the other compression tricks.  The simpler the better.  Divx and Xvid H.263 stuff is very similar but it might also trigger off the codec code in there AKA the 4Cs. I think it is a "DIVX" 4Cs which they will believe they can play, even if I am always using XVID to do it.  Some MS codecs worked but they are probably mpeg styles.

Simple MP3 audio mpeg1 layer 3 , stereo , the usual for that time 64Kbps low to 320 high, a 128 or 196 just fine.  44.1 or 48.0 sample rates, and 16 bit.  Keep it simple again, DVDs did the 5.1 dolby and 6 channel and all, dts, but AC3 (for example) never worked for me. There is one other one common to the dvd, never tried it.

Resolutions for a HD type tv, anything up to the usual 1080p or 1080i , in NTSC countries 30Fps or 60interleaved feilds , in SECAm or PAL places 25 or 50. or anything smaller.  Possibly limited to DVD reses which is 720x480 types in NTSC a little different 720x525 in pal.   (think dvd again which is basically what they were doing data style)  The chips do Scale ok from what I have seen

Video Bitrates 8000 or less for the video 10k for both max, just like dvd. Probably something more like 2-4k just to keep it all smooth and happy, make it easy.

That is some ideas, all of which would have to be tested out.  I have done that for many devices of that age/type and it is just a pattern I follow that just works.  I use virtual Dub, and have used FFMpeg & Mencoder, but with a GUI, because I am not into trying to type it all correctly on a command line.

Pictures I find it easy to mass convert to the actual res of the tv, like 1080 even for 720 tvs because they were designed to handle that fine, and interpolate it well. XNview (windows again) could race through  thousands of  pictures converting and filtering them so easily.   Once you converted the resolution, the size will decrease (so much) to where you might be able to maintain a 90% or even 100% jpeg compress.

The media chips are a bit slow, there is little codec support built into it, so anything that is smaller lighter more compressed to death will flow along better. It is all Older methods that were used widely during that time, and seemingly simple (to decode) stuff with only 2 codec tricks not 8-10. So keeping things simple and smaller will have it work quickly, and at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks man. The content and knowledge you have just shared is great. Thanks again.